# Access text file from web with VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to load a text file with VB .Net so that I can use it with a streamreader object. for example: www.fakesite.com/text.txt

Thanks

It is of a particular URL and is already present on the server

Comment: Is someone uploading the file to your site and you need to read it or do you need to get the text of a file at a particular URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and its [`GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method, which gives you a [`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) on which you can call [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to get a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) object to pass to your [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).

(Dizzy yet?)

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Function GetPage(ByVal PageURL As String) As String
    Dim S As String = ""
    Try
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(PageURL)
        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
            S = Reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("FAIL: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return S
End Function
```

You can call it with:

```
Dim Page As String = GetPage("http://randomurl.xxx/file.txt")
```